# git check if file exists on HEAD with SHA?

Tags: git, sha

I need to check if a file exists on the most recent commit (`HEAD`). I have been doing this with

```
git cat-file -e HEAD:path/to/file
```

but I realized this could be problematic if the file has been moved or renamed. Is there a way to check a file based on the SHA? I tried

```
git cat-file -e SHA
```

but it seems to search all commits, not just the most recent.

Based on [Alan Curry’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327054) this seems to work

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep SHA
```

Comment: Note to self: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L155-L158 could be of interest too: see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L155-L158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the output of `git ls-tree -r HEAD`